# "Passing arguments" via ThreadLocal ok?

Tags: java, oop, interface, static, thread-local

I'm building both a Java networking library and an application which makes use of it. The library consists of:

- An interface PacketSocket which has methods for sending and receiving packets of bytes.
- Two implementations of it, one over TCP and one over UDP.
- An ObjectConnection class which is built on top of a PacketSocket and handles serialization of objects to byte packets.

The application uses RequestConnection on top of a UDPPacketSocket. The UDPPacketSocket implementation is unique in that it supports specifying per packet whether delivery should be guaranteed. I would like to be able to use from within the application, but there is no way through the ObjectConnection and PacketSocket interfaces.

I could of course add a boolean guaranteed parameter to the applicable methods in those interfaces, but then I'd eventually (when there will be more implementations of PacketSocket) have to add many more parameters that are specific to certain implementations only and ignored by others.

Instead I though I could do it with a static thread-local property of UDPPacketSocket, like so:

```
class Application {

  public void sendStuff() {

    // is stored in a ThreadLocal, so this code is still thread-safe
    UDPPacketSocket.setGuaranteed(true);

    try {
       myObjCon.send(...);
    } finally {
       // ... restore old value of guaranteed
    }

  }
}
```

What do you think of an approach like that?

Comment: Well, it certainly feels like a hack, but I can't see why it could go wrong. In a code review, I would complain about it. It's kind of confusing and non-obvious.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it's sort of what Java2D does with `setStroke` and such, but deeper.

Answer (score 3):

I think its an ugly hack, however sometimes it is only option, esp if you are "passing" a value through many layers of code and you cannot easily modify that code.

I would avoid it if you can. A better option would be to have the following, if possible

```
 myObjCon.sendGuaranteed(...);
```

Comment: You could introduce an interface Packet, which represents the packets sent, with the method setGuaranteed(boolean b). All the objects that you send may implement that interface.

Comment: @weekens: The problem there is that I feed an object into `ObjectConnection`, but `UDPPacketSocket` gets a byte array. Or more generally, the object that would implement that interface gets destroyed before it reaches `UDPPacketSocket`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is an ugly hack.  It will work, but you may end up regretting doing it.

I'd deal with this by using a `Properties` object to pass the various `PacketSocket` implementation parameters. If that is unpalatable, define a `PacketSocketParameters` interface with a hierarchy of implementation classes for the different kinds of `PacketSocket`.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend some sort of "performance characteristics" parameter, maybe something like a Properties instance.  then, each impl could use their own, arbitrary properties (e.g. "guaranteed" for your current impl).  note, you can avoid string parsing by using the object methods on Properties (e.g. `get()` instead of `getProperty()`) or using a straight Map instance.  then your values could be true objects (e.g. Boolean).

Answer (score 0):

since we know it's a UDP, we can de-abstract the layers and access the concrete stuff

```
( (UDPSocket)connection.getSocket() ).setGuaranteed(true);
```

Comment: it is supposed to be a per-packet flag.